# Transforming the x-axis of a figure created with customticks package

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, packages

I have some data which i inter alia define and invert

```
dataYAG = {{0.0095, 25.07}, {0.05, 50.1}, {0.1, 58.7}, {0.2, 65.01}, {0.3, 66.8}, {0.4, 66.97}};


InvYAG = (dataYAG/100)^-1
```

which i plot than with usage of the **customticks** package

with

```
dataPlotYAG = 
ListPlot[InvYAG, PlotRange -> {{0, 12000}, {1, 5}}, 
Frame -> True,                      
FrameTicks -> {LinTicks[0, 12000, TickDirection -> Out, 
MajorTickLength -> 0.02, MinorTickLength -> 0.01, 
TickLabelFunction ->Function[x,Framed[If[Boole[IntegerQ[x/10000]] == 0, N[x/10000],IntegerPart[x/10000]], FrameStyle -> None]]], 
LinTicks[1, 5, TickDirection -> Out, MajorTickLength -> 0.02, 
MinorTickLength -> 0.01,TickLabelFunction -> (Framed[#2, FrameStyle -> None] &)], None,None}, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.003], Black]
        ]
```

i tried the condition

```
If[Boole[IntegerQ[x/10000]] == 0, N[x/10000], IntegerPart[x/10000]
```

to get rid of that, what obviously does not work.

[image]

Is this because x is not evaluated in my options so i run of course never in my conditions and is there a way to get rid of that points ? (which would of course only take me some seconds in illustrator)?

Cheers

Comment: To get rid of *what*? You do not describe clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot actually to point out that I tried to get rid of the decimal point for "0." and "1"

Answer (score 0):

It seems needlessly complex to write

```
If[Boole[IntegerQ[x/10000]] == 0, N[x/10000], IntegerPart[x/10000]
```

when

```
If[IntegerQ[x/10000], IntegerPart[x/10000], N[x/10000] ]
```

would do. (Notice that the arguments are reversed because you are now checking if `IntegerQ` is true, not false.)

I do not have the customticks package, but I suspect your problem is that you have defined a pure function (`Function`) without a terminating `&`. Try this `Slot`-notation version, with the terminating `&` and see if that helps.

```
Framed[If[IntegerQ[#/10000], IntegerPart[#/10000], N[#/10000]] &
```

You might also want to consider whether there are small rounding issues in your data, so that

```
Framed[If[IntegerQ[Chop[#/10000]], IntegerPart[#/10000], N[#/10000]] &
```

gets the result you want. You could also try `Round` or `Floor` instead of `IntegerPart`.

If you need something more sophisticated you could write a custom function like this one. In your case you would change the `n` to `n/10000`, or include a second argument that defines the denominator. You could also do this as an `If` rather than a `Switch`: it's in that form because the previous version of this function was more complicated.

```
numberformat[n_?NumericQ, opts:OptionsPattern[{NumberForm}]]:= 
  Switch[n, _Integer, NumberForm[n, Sequence@@FilterRules[{opts}, 
   Options[NumberForm]], DigitBlock -> 3, NumberSeparator -> "\[ThickSpace]"],
      _,  NumberForm[Chop@N[n], Sequence@@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NumberForm]]] ]
```